# Objective-CでAPNsサーバからのリモート通知受信について

Tags: ios

Objective-CでAPNsサーバからのリモート通知受信プログラムを作成しています。softbankのiphone10.2.1で通話中にリモート（プッシュ）通知を受信できるようにしたいです。

発生している問題

通話中にリモート（プッシュ）通知を受信できません。（didreceiveremotenotificationイベントが呼ばれません。） 
通話中でも該当のアプリケーションを前面にすると通知されますが、通話の画面が前面にあると通知されません。

該当のソースコード

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

//Push
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];


//iOS8対応
NSString *currentVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

if([currentVersion compare:@"8.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending){
// iOS7以前の処理
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
(UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

} else {
// iOS8の処理

UIUserNotificationType types = UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;

UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}

return YES;
}


-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{

// 中略

completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

}
```

試したこと

ペイロードで送信するAPS辞書の値は「content-available=1」にして、バックグラウンドでサイレント通知するようにしています。

補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

言語：Objective-C 
開発ツール：XCode Ver8.1

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/74220

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/10236